# How can I reinitialize all global variables in a static C library using visual studio 2008?

Tags: c, visual-studio

Basically I need a way to do this and I don't mind how ugly or dirty it gets to achieve this.

The reason being is the library is being hosted by the application for a simulation.   Somehow I have to be able to reset the simulation, therefore reset all the library back to a default state.  ( or as close as possible to the default state )

is it possible to find the global memory section and memcpy to it?

Not wanting to have to write something that manually resets every global variable.

any ideas welcome!

(not really interested in 'can't be done' or 'change the code so it doesn't have globals' type answers)

Comment: Reinitializing all global variables to their original values is vacuously easy if you follow a simple rule: don't have any global variables! :-)

Comment: R: Think you failed to understand the goal, the question is to do with hosting a static C library.  In C it's perfectly legal to have global / static state.   Hence in a simulation, How can you reset that libraries state.  It doesn't matter whether the lib is designed with global variables or not.  The fact is, its a legal thing to do, so it needs to be reset.  I'm not designing the libraries here, I'm designing something that uses the libraries and wants to reset everything into an initial state.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought, is unload and then reload the DLL.  On reload, the global vars should be reset.  Under windows there is a delay load and unload.  I've never used it; but it may be of some help.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96c1b5cf.aspx

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to implement the 'core' of the library as a DLL.  Have the public interface for the library be something separate (a DLL or static library - it doesn't much matter).  When the library is to be initialized, load the DLL portion.  When the library is to be de-initialized, unload it.

So a sequence that 'resets' the library would de-initialize then initialize, resulting in an unload/reload set of operations.

The only other work would be to implement thin wrappers that use `GetProcAddress()` and function pointers around the entry points to the DLL implementation.

Answer (score 0):

> Not wanting to have to **write something that manually resets every global variable**

That's the way to go.

Comment: And messing with the memory isn't?

Comment: our jobs are to mess with memory in new and creative ways :)

Comment: I'm not saying it isn't without its problems, but its pretty easy to test and see if it works